# Problems with app crashing in IOS 9 while locking and unlocking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, xcode7

My app is crashing in iOS 9 when we unlock the screen and unlock again.I dont have any issue in ios 8.

I am getting device log as

```
** -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ** unhandled action -> <FBSSceneSnapshotAction: 0x7c285b40> {
    handler = remote;
    info = <BSSettings: 0x7c285ba0> {
        (1) = 5;
    };
}
```

This is my appdidfinishlaunching method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.masterViewController = [[AppMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    [self loadMasterView];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

for loading first screen i am using a dispatch_queue and this is my method

```
-(void)loadMasterView
{
    // set the idle timer to be disabled.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    self.window.rootViewController =self.masterViewController;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        HomeScreenController *homeScreenController = [[HomeScreenController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenController" bundle:nil];
        homeScreenController.masterViewController = self.masterViewController;
        [self.masterViewController pushViewController:homeScreenController];
    });  
}
```

Could you guys please answer this.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...`